# Web part for Flash? Detecting Flash supportability?

Tags: web-part, 2007

I want to develop a web part (For: MOSS2007 and SP2010) that displays Flash file (.swf), and I found out this source code (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/sharepoint/MOSSFlashWebPart.aspx) which seems good.

However, my problem is that I want to improve this web part by letting the web part checks if the visitor's browser supports Flash or not. I have checked out the script on: (http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/download/detection_kit/), But I am not able to get it working within my web part.

In my web part, I am calling the script in page load. But it seems that the script runs before rendering html content. Therefore, I am unable to get the output from the script in the server side code.

**So, could you please tell me how to tackle this issue ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ScriptLink.Register control in your web part and specify the script path in it.

Further in your script add the SharePoint OOB JS mehod **_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("Check_Plugin");** and specify the JS method name that checks the browser plugin.

Any method specified in _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push would be called after the page HTML has finished loading.

ScriptLink.Register
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms450390.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can have the swf object in a html page with the browser support code and put a Page viewer webpart and show the html page in that